# jQuery - get all src of images in div and put into field

Tags: jquery, html, field, fetch, src

I want to modified [this tutorial](http://kimjoyfox.com/blog/creating-a-jquery-slideshow-adding-thumbnail-navigation/) to my requirements but there is one problem to me. I'm a beginner with jQuery and I would like to get all image sources from specifïc div and put them into field. There is a variable *images* which is field and contain some images but I want instead of this get all image sources from div and put them into field *images*. I know that isn't such a complicated but I don't really know how to do it.

The source is here http://jsfiddle.net/s5V3V/36/

This is the variable *image* from source on jsfiddle which I want fill from div instead what I have there now:

```
images = ['http://kimjoyfox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/drwho8.jpg',
    'http://kimjoyfox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/drwho7.jpg',
    'http://kimjoyfox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/drwho6.jpg',
    'http://kimjoyfox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/drwho5.jpg',
    'http://kimjoyfox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/drwho4.jpg',
    'http://kimjoyfox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/drwho3.jpg',
    'http://kimjoyfox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/dr-whos-tardis.png',
    'http://kimjoyfox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/drwho9.jpg',
    'http://kimjoyfox.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/drwho1.jpg'];
```

Thanks advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In dom ready try

```
var images = $('.thumbnailArrows').children('img').map(function(){
    return $(this).attr('src')
}).get()
```

Comment: The `.get()` is superfluous, as is wrapping `this` inside `$.map` with `jQuery`.

Comment: @AndréDion - `.get()` is needed because jQuery's `.map()` method which will return a jQuery object, not an array.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming by "field" you mean variable or Array:

```
var images = $('#imageHolder').find('img').map(function() { return this.src; }).get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just loop with .each() and get the attribute

```
(function(){
    var images = [];
    $("#imageHolder img").each(function(){
      images.push($(this).attr('src'))
    })
    console.log(images);
  })()
```

http://jsbin.com/ogekos/1/edit

Comment: Why the anonymous function?

Comment: I took his data and tested it here http://jsbin.com/ogekos/1/edit so it was easier for me to test it with anonymous function. Obviously it is not needed :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're saying you want to create a variable `images` that will be an array populated with the `src` URLs from all the img elements in your `thumbnails` div then you can do this:

```
var images = $("#thumbnails").find("img").map(function() { return this.src; }).get();
```

(If I've picked the wrong div as the container obviously you can correct that by replacing `"#thumbnails"` with a selector for whatever the right div is, perhaps `"#imageHolder"`.)

Note that your use of the term "field" is incorrect. You seem to mean "array", or possibly just "variable".

Answer (score 0):

find fix your problem :

```
   var images = $(".thumbnailArrows").find('img').map(function () {
                                                            return $(this).attr('src')
                                                        }).get()
```