# Converting the content in the textbox to the HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a project where I'll copy my HTML code to `<textarea>` and I need to fetch the values with in that...

For example `<img alt="hello">` is the content which I paste in to the `<textarea>`. When I click a button I need to search for `<img>` tags and I need to fetch the value of alt attribute that is "hello".
Here is the snippet I'm using.

```
<textarea rows="6" id="t">
    there is no
    love in the ghetto
    img
    <img alt="hello">
    so come here
    and get it
</textarea>
<input type="button" id="getline" value="get line" />
```

Above is the HTML code.
And this is the script I'm using to search and find the value of alt attribute.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#getline").click(function(){
        var str = $("#t").html();
        var srres= str.match(/img/gi);
        for(i=0;i<srres.length;i++)
        {
            var atim= $(""+srres[i]).attr("alt");
            alert(atim);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

But I'm getting the alert undefined.

Can anyone please assist me regarding this. That will be helpful for me.

Comment: Try `$('#t').val()` to get the content of the textarea

Comment: also use `console.log` instead of `alert` for debugging

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - get all src of images in div and put into field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18101673/jquery-get-all-src-of-images-in-div-and-put-into-field)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `val()` to get value of a textarea, not `html()`

You can then wrap that html string in jQuery object and use jQuery methods instead of regex to get what you need

```
$("#getline").click(function(){

    var $div = $('<div>').html(  $("#t").val() );
    $div.find('img').each(function(){
        console.log( this.alt);
    });   

});
```

Comment: Think $ is forgotten at the second line

Comment: @SerhatMERCAN sure was...fixed now. Thx

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty much there - just need `val()` instead of `html()` to get the text from the textarea:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#getline").click(function() {
    var str = $("#t").val();

    console.log(str);


    var srres = str.match(/img/gi);
    for (i = 0; i < srres.length; i++) {
      var atim = $("" + srres[i]).attr("alt");
      alert(atim);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img alt="hello">is the content which i paste in to the textarea, when i click a button i need to search for "img" and i need to fetch the value of alt attribute that is "hello". Here is the snippet I'm using.
<textarea rows="6" id="t">
  there is no love in the ghetto img
  <img alt="hello">so come here and get it
</textarea>
<input type="button" id="getline" value="get line" />
```