# Is there way to check if some <img> tag have same src=""?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to check if `<img>` or `<a>` tags have same `src`(`id`) and than click on one with same `src` or `id`
Here's example code:

```
<span>
    <a id="101" href="#">
        <img  src="101.png"></a>
    <a id="3" href="#">
        <img  src="3.png"></a>
    <a id="59" href="#">
        <img  src="59.png"></a>
    <a id="3" href="#">
        <img  src="3.png"></a>
</span>
```

Is there any way to do it with jquery or javascript?

i found solution,tnx for your answers :

```
    javascript:(function () {
  var ids = {};
  var found = false;
  $('[id]').each(function() {
    if (this.id && ids[this.id]) {
      found = true;
      console.warn('Duplicate ID #'+this.id);
      dupid=this.id;
      $('#'+dupid).click();
    }
    ids[this.id] = 1;
  });
  if (!found) console.log('No duplicate IDs found');
})();
```

Comment: But what do you want to do once you find a duplicate?

Comment: You can get jQuery to give you all the img elements, then iterate through them grabbing their src attributes. Use a Set to detect dups.

Comment: Why would you have two elements with the same `id` value? That's invalid HTML, not to mention illogical.

Comment: lets say it's some kind of captcha i want to make autoclick

Comment: So, you want to defeat a captcha and you want us to help you do it?

Answer (score 4):

You can use jquery to find all the `img` elements:

```
var list = $("IMG");
```

You can then refine the selector to find only images with a SRC of a certain value:

```
var list = $("IMG[SRC='image1']");
```

And then you can take a count:

```
var count = $("IMG[SRC='image1']").length;
```

If `count` > 1 then you have a duplicate.

Comment: But this assumes that you already know the specific `src` value to test. How would you find img elements with duplicate `src` without knowing the value(s) in advance?

Comment: You can [get an array of all SRC values on the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18101673/jquery-get-all-src-of-images-in-div-and-put-into-field) and use that in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

I did this little example with the help of this page: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_doc_images3

Here's the source and you can go there and test it.  It's not the compete answer but with a little extra work on your part you can probably figure out the rest. It gives you the original indices in the document.images array that are duplicates.  Of course you needn't output the original arrays or the sorted array but I just like to be able to see what I'm doing.  The final indices give you direct access to the duplicate images.

```
 <body>

  <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/klematis.jpg" alt="flower" width="150" height="113">
  <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/klematis.jpg" alt="flower" width="150" height="113">
  <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/klematis2.jpg" alt="flower" width="152" height="128">
  <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42">
  <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/klematis.jpg" alt="flower" width="150" height="113">

  <p>Click the button to display the URL of the first image (index 0) in the document.</p>

  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

  <p id="demo"></p>
  <p id="result"></p>
  <p id="answer"></p>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      line = '';
      var duplicates = false;
      var imageA = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < document.images.length; i++) {
        imageA[i] = [];
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += '<br />' + document.images[i].src;
        imageA[i].push(document.images[i].src);
        imageA[i].push(i);
      }
      imageA.sort();
      var firsttime = true;
      for (var i = 0; i < document.images.length; i++) {
        var n = i + 1;
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += '<br />' + n + ' - ' + imageA[i];
        if (i > 0) {
          if (imageA[i][0] == imageA[i - 1][0]) {
            if (!firsttime) line += ', ';
            duplicates = true;
            var num = imageA[i][1];
            line += num;
            firsttime = false;
          }
        }
      }
      if (duplicates) {
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = 'The follow indices of the original document.images array are duplicates: ';
        document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML += line + '.';
      }
    }
    </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

First we have the `url` of the image which we want to check, and declare the selector:

```
var url = (an image url);
var img = $('img[src='+url+']');
```

To count number of `img` that have same url:

```
var num = img.length;
```

To click one of them (the first one):

```
if (num > 1) img.first().click();
```

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable way would be to use [CSS attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to select all images with the matching `src`, then check the `length` property of the collection returned. You can either do it in jQuery or using [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) which also accepts CSS selectors as input.

```
function hasDuplicate(src) {
    var images = document.querySelectorAll('img[src="'+src+'"]');

    return images.length > 1;
}

// OR in jQuery

function hasDuplicate(src) {
    return $('img[src="'+src+'"]').length > 1
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `src^=` instead of `src=`? This will treat them as duplicates if one is a prefix of the other, e.g. `src=foo` and `src=foobar`. Admittedly, this is an unlikely pairing, because image URLs usually have distinct suffixes, and you wouldn't have another image that begins with a suffixed name.

Comment: You're right. It was meant to be `*=` to allow for non-exact URLs, but now that I've written that down, it doesn't make any more sense than `^=`. Changing my answer to simply use `=`.